# How to Handle NPE

Tags: android

In my application I have to fill the views using web service responses.

I am getting the correct web service response, but at the time of filling the views using the response I get an NPE when running on a device. However, when run in the emulator it's working properly.

I cannot find the cause of the NPE, below is my code, can anyone help?

The exception is raised in the `getview()` method at `r2(holder.r2.setRating(ksrating_value_w_onedecimal);)`.

The stack trace:

```
07-20 17:21:21.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4144): java.lang.NullPointerException

07-20 17:21:21.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at com.ibkr.roadbrake.RB_StaticSearchResults$StaticSearchResultsListViewAdapter.getView(RB_StaticSearchResults.java:810)

07-20 17:21:21.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1385)

07-20 17:21:21.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1213)

07-20 17:21:21.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1126)

07-20 17:21:21.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8020)
07-20 17:21:21.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
```

And the java file:

```
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  {           
        class ViewHolder 
        {                
            RatingBar r1,r2,r3;
            TextView ratingpts, ratingpks, ratingprr;               
        }
        ViewHolder holder;

        //if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.stsearchresults_eachitem, null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();             
            holder.r1 = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.small_ratingbar);
            holder.ratingpts = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingpts);                
            holder.r2 = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.kssmall_ratingbar);
            holder.ratingpks = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingpks);
            holder.r3 = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rrsmall_ratingbar);
            holder.ratingprr = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingprr);


            /*convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }     */     

        float rating = RB_Constant.filterSearchResultObj.response.get(position).Rating;
        float rating_value = Math.round(rating * 10);           
    float rating_value_w_onedecimal = rating_value / 10;            

        try
        {
            holder.r1.setRating(rating_value_w_onedecimal);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error->"+e.toString()+" position "+position);
        }            
        holder.ratingpts.setText(""+rating_value_w_onedecimal);     

        float ksrating = RB_Constant.filterSearchResultObj.response.get(position).KidsRating;
        float ksrating_value = Math.round(ksrating * 10);           
        float ksrating_value_w_onedecimal = ksrating_value / 10;
        try{
            holder.r2.setRating(ksrating_value_w_onedecimal);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error->"+e.toString()+" position "+position);
        }            
        holder.ratingpks.setText(""+ksrating_value_w_onedecimal);  

        float rrrating = RB_Constant.filterSearchResultObj.response.get(position).RestRoomRating;
        float rrrating_value = Math.round(rrrating * 10);           
        float rrrating_value_w_onedecimal = rrrating_value / 10;
        try{
            holder.r3.setRating(rrrating_value_w_onedecimal);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error->"+e.toString()+" position "+position);
        }            
        holder.ratingprr.setText(""+rrrating_value_w_onedecimal);  
      ------------
      ------------
      ------------
   }
```

Comment: Look which of the strings can be null and be passed as an argument.

Comment: i got exception at r2(rating bar2). i got correct ws response. it works in the emulator without NPE but in device i got NPE at r2.

Comment: is it clear or  you need any information?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I now understand what's going wrong. Error occurs in this method:

```
  holder.r2.setRating(ksrating_value_w_onedecimal);
```

which means that either holder or r2 is null. Because holder is initialized with a call to `new ViewHolder()`, that could only be null if it throws an exception, so that's not the problem. Next you call

```
  holder.r2 = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.kssmall_ratingbar);
```

which seems to be your problem. The findViewById() method returns null if it can't find the id being referenced.

So, look at `stsearchresults_eachitem.xml` and verify that you have an id `kssmall_ratingbar` -- I suspect that's where your problem is.

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE:**

NullPointerExceptions are usually pretty easy if you just look at the line which is causing the exception. In this case, take a look at:

> com.ibkr.roadbrake.RB_StaticSearchResults$StaticSearchResultsListViewAdapter.getView(RB_StaticSearchResults.java:810)

Examine each variable and determine if it could be null; one of them definitely is. Then figure out why that is null. Keep doing that until you find the problem. Hope that gives enough info.

BTW, I don't see any code which calls an r2() method, so I don't understand when you say:

> The exception is raised in the getview() method at r2(holder.r2.setRating(ksrating_value_w_onedecimal);).

Comment: As an extension..

Nesting calls always makes your program more difficult to examine.  It's always best to avoid nesting calls like that.  Try to assign return values to a variable before passing it to another call.  This way it will make it easier to see which call returned a null.

Comment: Yeah, for example with RB_Constant.filterSearchResultObj.response.get(position).RestRoomRating, there are 4 different things that could be null and result in an NPE. I tend to have no more than two in a single line.

Comment: But here i am getting correct value(ksrating_value_w_onedecimal). Only exception raises at "holder.r2.setRating(ksrating_value_w_onedecimal);"

Comment: in my problem r2 is not method. i am using that just pointing purpose in the below code. But it is working in emulator but i got NPE in device.

Comment: Ahh, ok. So either holder or r2 is null. If the first access to holder throws an NPE (in your first throw block), then holder is null; otherwise r2 is null. I suggest finding which variable is null and why that is. After you know that, then worry about emulator vs device, because it could literally be anything.

Comment: Ok, I see what's going on now -- it can't find the id. Updated the response.